# How to dymanically import monaco-editor min version?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, monaco-editor

My project needs to use only the diff editor features, only for showing code's difference, doesn't need to be editable. But it seems the dependency is large by following the official guide of integration. So i wanna cut down the size to improve the website's performance.

Here is the way i use monaco-editor in my project:

```
npm install monaco-editor
```

And in the code, because it's too huge, so i decided to prefetch:

```
if (!this.monaco) {
    this.monaco = await import(
    /* webpackPrefetch: true;" */'monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.api.js'
    );
}
```

However, when it's built by webpack, i found out the chunks is very big, about 5MB.

I am searching the way that i can only import diff-editor features (if it is supported), or the min-version by dynamically imported. But i didn't get the exactlly way.

Actually i tried this:

```
this.monaco = await import(
    /* webpackPrefetch: true;" */'monaco-editor/min/vs/editor/editor.main.js'
);
```

But there is error shown 'is not a module.ts(2306)'. I am kind of hopeless.

I very appreciate if anyone can give me some advices. :)